# No resources loaded on IOS after upgrading to latest Aurelia stable?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

After updating from beta to the latest stable my Aurelia site no longer loads any resources.

Works fine on desktops but on iphones (both safari and chrome) the page is blank.

Looking in the developer tools the console output is identical up until "aurelia started". After that line the desktop loads resources:

```
INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started
aurelia-d139ec294f.js:7 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://getbeer.se/dist/app.html ["http://getbeer.se/dist/nav-bar", "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"]
aurelia-d139ec294f.js:7 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://getbeer.se/dist/nav-bar.html []
aurelia-d139ec294f.js:7 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://getbeer.se/dist/search/search.html ["http://getbeer.se/dist/search/sort-picker", "http://getbeer.se/dist/search/filter-picker"]
aurelia-d139ec294f.js:7 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://getbeer.se/dist/search/sort-picker.html []
aurelia-d139ec294f.js:7 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://getbeer.se/dist/search/filter-picker.html []
```

But the mobile browsers just does nothing

```
INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started
```

Looking at the network traffic they are identical up until app-build-xyz

After that the desktop loads fetch@0.11.0.js but the safari does nothing. Could this be a poly-fill issue? (how come it worked in the beta)

Ideas on how to debug this further?

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes during the router lifecycle, if something fails just right in a VM, it will stop the page from loading and not have any errors logged. What you can try to do is strip out any loading of other modules, and try and build back up to find out what module is causing the errors

Comment: @Andreas did you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Same problem. Anyone get this fixed?

Comment: I started fresh and copied the files over , now it works, no idea why